# Single quotes in query

Tags: query

We have a custom object with fields that are alphanumeric plus `* ' ( ) and -` .  My query works fine for everything but a single-quote.  I need to search a specific field (in this example it is Name) IN a group of strings.  Below is for matching on `pgm.Name__c`.  If I do not select a program name that has a single-quote then the query returns lots of records perfectly.  If I include the Alzheimer's program name ( or Children's or anything with 's then I get an error message.  **expecting a right parentheses, found 's'**

```
SELECT .... FROM Program__c pgm WHERE ( pgm.Name__c IN ( 'Alzheimer's Disease Initiative (ADI)', 'Adult Care Food Program (ACFP)', 'AmeriCorps*VISTA (Volunteers in Service to America)' ) )
```

If I use escapeSingleQuotes then I get the following:
[image]

Of course pgm.Name will never match any of these.  Is there a way to reformat pgm.Name__c to match the reformatted items in the where clause?  If I replace 's with s or anything else then it will not match.  I need pgm.Name__c to look in he strings and pull back all the records it matches.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass literal string to IN operator, you need to escape the single quote **within** the string only.

```
'Alzheimer\'s Disease Initiative (ADI)'
```

Comment: Do replaceAll('\'s,', '\\'s');  ?   escapeSingleQuotes  did all single-quotes.

Comment: You cannot use apex method inside the soql. However you can use it in building a list as in the example given by @MarkPond before passing it to the soql

Comment: I learned that I cannot use apex method inside the soql.  I was able to get WHERE ( pgm.Name__c IN ( 'Alzheimer\'s Disease Initiative (ADI)', 'AmeriCorps State Grants' ) )  by using escapeSingleQuotes in the code where I was constructing the string.  dataQueryStr += '\'' +    String.escapeSingleQuotes(so.getLabel())    + '\'';  So when it put the whole query string together it had what you showed me with the escape single quote only within the string.   Thanks, Hengky.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the issue as well as jumping ahead a little bit in your implementation, using a `List<String>` and variable binding in addition to escaping single quotes is probably going to be your best solution long term.

This implementation is also a lot more readable and less error prone.

```
List<String> programNames = new List<String>();
programNames.add('Alzheimer\'s Disease Initiative (ADI)');
programNames.add('Adult Care Food Program (ACFP)');
programNames.add('AmeriCorps*VISTA (Volunteers in Service to America)');
```

---

```
pgm.Contact__r.MailingPostalCode, pgm.Keywords__c FROM Program__c
WHERE Pgm.Name__c IN :programNames
ORDER BY pgm.Name__c
```

Comment: Actually I do have a List.  In my post I showed what it turned into.                   programssearchQuery += ' WHERE ( pgm.Name__c IN ( ' + dataQueryStr + ' ) ) ORDER BY pgm.Name__c' ; 
My dataQueryStr is all the things you have in your programNames.add and are separated by commas.

Comment: don't stringify the IN collection, bind to the list directly